# How to hide table if data is not there and show if its data there(PHP,PDO)

Tags: php, pdo

Iam getting the records in tabular format and displaying the data in front end but if there is no data i need to hide total table including table headings.here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<head>
<style>
   table, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
   }
   th{
    width: 100px !important;
    background:#E1EBEC !important;
   }
   tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background:#999 !important;

</style>

</head>
<?php

$id = "ACDB-";

$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$number = str_pad($user_ID, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);

$ESTCCB_ID=$id.$number;

echo"<b>Show My Application</b>";

echo "<table class="table">";
echo "<tr><th>ApplicationID</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Email</th>             
<th>Company</th>
<th>How you want to collaborate with us?</th>
<th>Number boards you need to </th>
<th>Special_requirements</th><th>Details on Collaboration Request</th>  
<th>Status</th>
<th>Application Review Comments</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator {
 function __construct($it) {
     parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY);
 }

 function current() {
     return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
 }

 function beginChildren() {
     echo "<tr>";
 }

 function endChildren() {
     echo "</tr>" . "\n";
 }
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "*******";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "**********";

try {
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname",$username,         $password);
 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT Application_ID,name,email,company,collaborateMS,ARM64_Board,collaboration_Details,special_requirements,Status,Application_Comments FROM wp3_cte where userid='$ESTCCB_ID' ");
 $stmt->execute();

 // set the resulting array to associative
 $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) {
     echo $v;
   }

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

I need to hide these total table if there is no data in database and should display the form.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to improve the separation of logic and presentation in your application. Call the query *before* drawing the table and add an if statement to the whole table.

This should help you checking for results: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php